# How can I enable dark mode on Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate so that the setting page has a dark mode?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

How can I enable dark mode on Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate so that the setting page (`chrome://settings/`) has a dark mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`

[image]

Result on chrome://settings/:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has no system wide dark mode, therefore Chrome can't use the system settings.

The only other way I know is to start Chrome with the command-line parameter `--force-dark-mode`.

Therefore create or modify a link to Chrome so that it starts Chrome this way:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --force-dark-mode
```